# Vue component is not inserted when called in HTML code

Tags: vue.js

I try to use Vue components, but it is not working.

I also use Pug(Jade) like preprocessor.

But in result HTML code I have raw template without transformation from Vue component to HTML code.

Here is Vue component:

```js
Vue.component('date-input', {
  props: ['id', 'format', 'value'],
  mounted: function() {
    $(this.$el).children().last().datepicker({
      autoclose: true,
      format: this.format || 'dd.mm.yyyy',
      language: 'ru'
    });
  },
  beforeDestroy: function() {
    $(this.$el).children().last().datepicker('destroy');
  },
  methods: {
    onInput: function(event) {
      this.$emit('input', event.target.value);
    },
    onIconClick: function() {
      $(this.$el).children().last().datepicker('show');
    }
  },
  template: '<div class="date-field">' +
    '<span class="icon calendar" @click="onIconClick"></span>' +
    '<input id="id" class="form-control" type="text" @input="onInput" :value="value">' +
    '</div>'
});
```

Here is PUG code:

```pug
    +agreementModal('MYMODAL','MODAL NAME')
        .date-range.text-nowrap
            date-input.mr-3
            date-input
```

Result HTML code:

```html
<div class="date-range text-nowrap">
    <date-input class="mr-3"></date-input>
    <date-input></date-input>
</div>
```

Comment: What transformation do you expect to get ? Consider using single-file Vue components - you life will get simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

You do not seem to [initialize your Vue app](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Creating-a-Vue-Instance) (with `new Vue()`) at some point.

Declaring `Vue.component` is important so that `Vue` knows what to do with your custom components, but you still need to tell Vue to start managing a part of your DOM by initializing it.

```js
Vue.component('date-input', {
  props: ['id', 'format', 'value'],
  mounted: function() {
    $(this.$el).children().last().datepicker({
      autoclose: true,
      format: this.format || 'dd.mm.yyyy',
      language: 'ru'
    });
  },
  beforeDestroy: function() {
    $(this.$el).children().last().datepicker('destroy');
  },
  methods: {
    onInput: function(event) {
      this.$emit('input', event.target.value);
    },
    onIconClick: function() {
      $(this.$el).children().last().datepicker('show');
    }
  },
  template: '<div class="date-field">' +
    '<span class="icon calendar" @click="onIconClick"></span>' +
    '<input id="id" class="form-control" type="text" @input="onInput" :value="value">' +
    '</div>'
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>

<div id="app" class="date-range text-nowrap">
  <date-input class="mr-3"></date-input>
  <date-input></date-input>
</div>
```